# First time creating a PHP function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm still fairly new to PHP, and had no idea where else to turn for help on this.

The function I'm trying to create works *not* as a function, but once I turn it into a function it breaks. I plan to use this function several times on the page with arguments.

The ideal function is to gather all custom post terms into an array, sort the array and then echo out the HTML code.

Thank you for any help that can be offered.

```
<?php
function postTerms($termName)
{
    $postTermsArray = array();
    rewind_posts(); while (have_posts()) : the_post();      
    $postTerms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $termName, array("fields" => "names"));   
    $postTermsArray = array_merge($postTermsArray, $postTerms);
    $postTermsArray = array_unique($postTermsArray);
    endwhile;
    sort($postTermsArray);
    foreach($postTermsArray as $postTerms) {
        if ($postTerms !=''){
            $postTermsLower = strtolower($postTerms);
            $postTermsLower = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\%&-]/s', '', $postTermsLower);
            $postTermsLower = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $postTermsLower);
            echo ('<li><a href="#filter-'.$postTermsLower.'" data-filter-value=".'.$postTermsLower.'">'.$postTerms.'</a></li>');
        }
    }
}
postTerms();
?>
```

Comment: what about it "doesnt work"

Comment: where exactly are you defining `$post`? I don't believe WP sets that for you, so inside a function it'll be an undefined var.

Comment: That really doesn't look like `first time` function.

Comment: It echos nothing. I think there is a problem some where in the foreach loop, because I can echo out information outside the foreach loop.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I have a background in Javascript and JQuery, but I have actually never written a PHP  function before.

Comment: @SamuelCook Then what do you think the `endwhile` is for? To look pretty?

Comment: OP, the `while/endwhile` form of this loop is generally used only in 'view layer' or 'template layer' code. Here, the brace form should be preferred, like you have for your `foreach` and `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you are not giving a value to the `$termName` parameter. Since there's no default value either, it won't work.

Aside from that, you appear to be referencing variables from outside the scope, such as `$post->ID`. Functions can only access variables from the outside if:

1. They are passed as parameters
2. It is an anonymous function with a `use` clause (`$var = function($param) use ($outsidevar) {...}`), OR
3. You put `global $outsidevar` inside the function to "import" it.

<sub>(Also 4. You can use `$GLOBALS['outsidevar']`, but it's not recommended because building `$GLOBALS` is expensive)</sub>

Address the above issues and your function should work, although at the moment it looks like a function for the sake of a function. Everything you write in code MUST have a reason to it, preferably one that is written in a simple comment before you actually do it.

Comment: Wow I totally forgot about passing the outside variables, thank you. I will try this now.

Comment: The problem was like you said, $post->ID was not able to access the variables outside the function. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide an argument to your function, just calling:

```
postTerms();
```

You need to do:

```
postTerms($argument);
```